# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding

Tags: layout, android-actionbar-compat

In the appcompat_v7 in layout resources, shows me this error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'layout_marginTop' with value
>   '@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding').

This line code shows me an error are this (for `ImageView` from abc_action_bar_home.xml):

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
```

I found the solution by adding the word `_material`, like this:

```
"@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
```

I found the solution [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/mediarouter/R.dimen.html).

Answer (score 3):

The old [action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) is now known as the [app bar](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) and is a kind of [toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) in [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#) that came with Android Lollipop. Many of the metrics have changed and thus so has the naming of many of the values in [R.dimen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/mediarouter/R.dimen.html).

So as you discovered

`abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding`

is now called

`abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material`.

As an extra, here is a graphic from the [Android docs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) that shows some of the new default metrics:

[image]

Note that these defaults can change based on the device and orientation. For example,

Default height:

- Mobile Landscape: 48dp
- Mobile Portrait: 56dp
- Tablet/Desktop: 64dp